# calculate total count

Tags: mysql

We have table structure and data like

```
Id | startdate | enddate   | price
1. |  1 jan    | 30 Jan    | 100
2  |  1 Feb    | 28 Feb    | 200
3. |  1 March  |  31 March | 300
```

Now I want to calculate total price between the date range. Like from 1 Jan to 28 Feb total count will be 300, from 1 Feb to 31 March total count will.be 500, how to write query for this

Comment: To write some useful sql on this structure, you should have your dates in 'DateTime' format.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this,

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-02-28'
```

Please note that this might not be the correct MySQL syntax, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If these are stored as date fields you can do something like

```
Select SUM(Price) from Table where startdate > DD/MM/YYYY and enddate < DD/MM/YYYY
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your dates in the [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) format. 
Then we will simply perform a [SUM](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php) on the table with the appropriate `WHERE` conditions.

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM tablename WHERE startdate > '2012-01-01' AND enddate < '2012-02-28'
```